# Need to find video in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, video, phantomjs

I need to find if the DOM contains video or not. I want to find video irrespective of what way it is inserted in DOM.

I tried phantomJS but did not get any comprehensive way k

Comment: look at [element-selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Comment: Do you mean <video>?

Comment: Discribe your problem a bit more in detail. Should it be only the video-tag, only onload, periodically,...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('video').length){  //search for any video tag inside DOM
    alert("here"); // do whatever you want here
  }
});
```